# Hardware accelerated JPEG encoding

Tags: python, camera, gpu

I'm doing hardware accelerated JPEG conversion according to MMAL part of picamera docs.

Now it works only once, for second it shows next error:

"picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: cannot send buffer to port vc.ril.image_encode:in:0: Out of memory"

I almost sure that I missed some necessary routine with input port, but I failed to find correct way.

I use RPI 4 4 Gb with 512MB GPU memory. The code is

```
from picamera import mmal, mmalobj as mo
from threading import Event
import numpy as np
import io

class jpeg_encoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.encoder = mo.MMALImageEncoder()

        self.encoder.inputs[0].format = mmal.MMAL_ENCODING_RGB24
        self.encoder.inputs[0].framesize = (1280, 720)
        self.encoder.inputs[0].framerate = 30
        self.encoder.inputs[0].commit()
        self.encoder.inputs[0].enable(lambda port, buf: True)

        self.encoder.outputs[0].copy_from(self.encoder.inputs[0])
        self.encoder.outputs[0].format = mmal.MMAL_ENCODING_JPEG
        self.encoder.outputs[0].commit()
        self.encoder.outputs[0].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_JPEG_Q_FACTOR] = 50      
        self.encoder.outputs[0].enable(self.image_callback)     
        
        self.in_buffer = self.encoder.inputs[0].get_buffer()
        self.out_buffer=io.BytesIO()
        self.finished=Event()

    def image_callback(self,port, buf):
        self.out_buffer.write(buf.data)
        if buf.flags & mmal.MMAL_BUFFER_HEADER_FLAG_FRAME_END:
            self.finished.set()
            return True
        return False
        
    def encode(self,bytes_img):
        self.finished.clear()
        self.in_buffer.data=bytes_img
        self.encoder.inputs[0].send_buffer(self.in_buffer)
        if not self.finished.wait(1):
            raise Exception('capture timed out')
        self.out_buffer.seek(0)
        return self.out_buffer

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    test_img=np.zeros((720,1280,3),dtype=np.uint8)
    test_img[358:362,:,:]=255
    test_img[:,638:642,:]=255#some kind of generated test image
    
    enc=jpeg_encoder()
    buf=enc.encode(test_img.tobytes())
    
    with open('generated1.jpg','wb') as f:
        f.write(buf.read()) #all is good here, correct file successfully writed
    
    buf1=enc.encode(test_img.tobytes())#but here it fails
    
    with open('generated2.jpg','wb') as f:
        f.write(buf1.read())
```